# Can I exclude a base class member from the derived class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

Let's say I have a class called `CWindow`:

```
class CWindow
{
public:
    virtual bool Create();
};
```

In the derived class `CMyWindow`, I want to overload the `Create(void)` method to `Create(int someParam)`, BUT, I do not want the user to be able to call the `Create(void)` method, only the `Create(int someParam)`. Is this possible? Could I do:

```
class CMyWindow : public CWindow
{
private:
    bool Create();
public:
    virtual bool Create(int someParam);
};
```

Is this valid? Will it basically make the formerly public member of `CWindow` be a private member of `CMyWindow`?

I imagine if it IS possible to 'exclude' a member from a class, that this is closest to doing so, because AFAIK there is no magic `youcantbeamember` keyword in C++

My best guess is that no, you cannot do this. But I'm just hoping because I would like to avoid making a base class that has everything except for the `Create()` member, and deriving `CWindow` and `CMyWindow` from `CWindowBase`.

Comment: It's perfectly valid code, and should work fine.

Comment: `static_cast<CWindow*>(ptrToCMyWindow)->Create();` will be always possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* actually do this, and it will work as expected. The only problem is that a `CMyWindow` is still a `CWindow`, which allows `Create()`:

```
CMyWindow w;
w.Create(); // does not compile
static_cast<CWindow>(w).Create(); // compiles just fine
```

If you don't want to allow this at any cost then you have to make `CWindow::Create` abstract and possibly provide the current implementation (if any) as a `protected` member that derived classes can call explicitly:

```
class CWindow
{
public:
    virtual bool Create() = 0;
protected:
    bool DefaultCreateImplementation();
};

class CNormalWindow : public CWindow
{
public:
    bool Create() { return DefaultCreateImplementation(); }
}

class CMyWindow : public CWindow
{
private:
    virtual bool Create(); // declared but not defined
                           // if called by accident will produce linker error
public:
    virtual bool Create(int someParam);
};
```

Comment: Hm, I get linker error with this on `CMyWindow::Create(void)` without calling any Create method (vc2012).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you publicly inherit from CWindow to inherited its implementation. This should not be your intent when using public inheritance. Public inheritance means inheritance of interface. But you don't want to inherit CWindows interface, you want to hide it!

Think about an alternative design like this

```
class Window
{
public:
    // EVERY Window can create the window using this method
    virtual bool Create();  
};


class MyWindow : public Window
{
public:
    // Initialize MyWindow with an additional parameter, 
    // that is used to create the window
    MyWindow(int param);

    // Create the window using the parameter
    virtual bool Create() override;
private:
    int param;
};

class View
{
public:
    void AddWindow(Window& window)
    {
        myWindows.Add(&window);
        window.Create();  // I can call this on EVERY Window instance
    }
};
```